# 関数をロードしようとしているのですが出来ず困っています

Tags: haskell

```
baby.hs:2:35: error: parse error on input ‘\’
  |
2 | \cocoatextscaling0\cocoaplatform0{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
  |                                   ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

このような文が出て出来ないでいます
教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 出力を見る限り Haskell ファイルではなさそうに見えるのですが、baby.hs はどのようなファイルですか？（内容や、手に入れた経緯など）

Answer (score 2):

もしかして、macOSに標準で入っている「テキストエディット」で作成したファイルではないでしょうか？テキストエディットは、特に指定しないで保存すると、「リッチテキスト」というGHCiが（そのほか、大抵のプログラミング言語の処理系も）解釈できない形式で保存してしまいます。

テキストエディット以外のエディター、例えばVisual Studio Codeを使うのをおすすめします。